# 'Receiver (<ViewController>) has no segue with identifier 'addSegue'

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uistoryboardsegue

I have a navigation controller that has a segue links between them called "addSegue". When I click on the `tableView` cell though the app crashes and I get the error below:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<MSAddFriendsViewController: 0x98cc340>) has no segue with identifier 'addSegue'
```

I don't think that I have any issues with my code. Here is the method in which I have the line `showSegueWithIdentifier`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSMutableSet *selectedUsers = [NSMutableSet set];

[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];


cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
PFRelation *friendsRelation = [self.currentUser relationforKey:@"friendsRelation"];
PFUser *user = [self.allUsers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[friendsRelation addObject:user];
[self.currentUser saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);

    }    }];

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"addSegue" sender:self];

}
```

[Here is a picture of my storyboard](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1Of4oDADQCQbXJuT3J3Y3pQNFU/edit?usp=sharing)

[Here is an updated picture of my storyboard](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1Of4oDADQCQbXJuT3J3Y3pQNFU/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Check the Segue identifier you have given in Storyboard.

Comment: Clean the project & try again.

Comment: You should post the picture of your storyboard on a site that doesn't require permission for people to see it.

Answer (score 16):

I had this same problem and actually my problem was that I was calling

```
WRONG: [self.navigationController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowVerify" sender:self];
```

instead of

```
CORRECT: [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowVerify" sender:self];
```

so check that you are calling correct performSegueWithIdentifier method :)

Comment: nice one, this was the case for me

Comment: Thanks, I had reverse case.

Answer (score 11):

[image]

```
use segue identifier in Push Method and give the proper connection
```

if you are using `Identifier`, then call this line where u need

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"identifierName" sender:self];
```

**Swift 2.X**

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("identifierName", sender: self)
```

**Swift 3**

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "identifierName", sender: self)
```

---

Regarding the new screen you have added that way. In that screen, when you're finished and want to remove it, it's just:

```
self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Comment: How to pass the value to next view controller with this method?

Comment: @Aniruddha --  yesterday I already answered for your question,if u don't mine I solved ur issue, can u send your project in mail id karthik.saral@gmail.com

Comment: I'm using Storyboard. I have 2 classes A and B. From A, I want to pass the value to B. This is how I done it but it is not working. `B *bb = [[B alloc]init]; b.strName = @"Abcd"; [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueName" sender:nil];`. Please don't mind I cannot send you the project.

Comment: @Aniruddha - its K man, use this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19739037/pass-data-to-view-controller-using-storyboard-segue-ios otherwise say ur mail id i send the sample code in different methods, k

Answer (score 6):

Hard to say for sure, but some other people have had similar problems:

- In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568034/nsinvalidargumentexception-reason-receiver-has-no-segue-with-identifier), the asker instantiated the storyboard with
  `init` instead of `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` so the
  segue wasn't set up properly.
- In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874200/nsinvalidargumentexception-receiver-has-no-segue-with-identifier), it was just something weird going on
  internally with xcode and the simulator, and running Product->Clean
  helped.
- And of course, it's possible the segue name in the code doesn't match the segue name on the Storybord, but I'm guessing you've checked that a lot of times already!

Answer (score 0):

Check whether UIKIT being or not in header file. I unknowingly made new VC a subclass of View Controller.