# Receiver (<ViewController>) has no segue with identifier ''

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uisplitview

![enter image description here][1]Before posting I have read questions with similar issues but their fix didnt work for me hence my posting.
i am having an issue with an app and i was advised to use storyboards to fix it. As a result i followed this link
http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=3834
to move my xib to my storyboard.
Then, in custom class

- Entered "SecondView"(since that was where the nib was called) so the
  button of the newview says "SecondView"
- Since the app is a uisplitview i right click and dragged the "yellow
  icon" from the detailviewcontroller to my newview and selected push,
  destination current and identified name: next. ( Correct me if this
  step is wrong.
- Navigated to secondview.h and entered this code   `[self
  performSegueWithIdentifier:@"next" sender:self];` `in viewDidLoad`

However, strangly enough i get the error that secondView has no segue named next.
Looking at this link
['Receiver (<ViewController>) has no segue with identifier 'addSegue'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20715462/receiver-viewcontroller-has-no-segue-with-identifier-addsegue)
I seem to have done everything that was done in the image except that he used a button and I want to call it programmatically. 
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rq0r8.jpg

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Don't forget to set storyboard segues id: next

Comment: I uploaded a pic but I dont seem to have forgotten the segue id. Also i dragged from the detailview that is next to the "forthview" ( renamed it) unto the it and then selected push

Comment: click on the push segue (see arrow in screenshot) and set the segue id.

Comment: I have done so, please look at my screenshot, there is a link to it in the orginal question

Comment: Hi, i changed the link i uploaded too, sorry for taking you away from stackover flow but i dont have enough rep to post an image. I assure you it's simply the image that is on that link

Comment: Oh Understood, sadly I dont have enough rep to post a pic.

Comment: It helps me..to fix it..!