# Redirect View login using xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Good morning,

I'm trying to create the login and register process in my first iOS app and I'm a little bit lost. I tried to search a lot of post regarding the redirect but it's never working in my app and I really need your help with that.

That's my Storyboard:

http://autograpp.com/View.jpg

And I would like to redirect the user to the 'Main' when the user is logged in correctly and when the user is registered correctly. I will be much appreciated if you can help me with this problem because I'm really stuck with this problem.

I will also add the code from my ViewController.m (AupViewController.m) if that helps you:

```
#import "aupViewController.h"
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
#import "SBJson.h"

@implementation MainViewController

@end

@implementation aupViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.loginButton.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email"];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"]];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end

@interface NSURLRequest (DummyInterface)

+ (BOOL)allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:(NSString*)host;

+ (void)setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:(BOOL)allow forHost:(NSString*)host;

@end

@implementation LoginViewController

-(IBAction)textFieldReturn:(id)sender
{
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
}
- (IBAction)backgroundClick:(id)sender
{
    [txtPassword resignFirstResponder];
    [txtUsername resignFirstResponder];
    [_txtMail resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    if ([txtPassword isFirstResponder] && [touch view] != txtPassword) {
        [txtPassword resignFirstResponder];
    }
    if ([txtUsername isFirstResponder] && [touch view] != txtUsername) {
        [txtUsername resignFirstResponder];
    }
    if ([_txtMail isFirstResponder] && [touch view] != _txtMail) {
        [_txtMail resignFirstResponder];
    }
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

@synthesize txtUsername;
@synthesize txtPassword;

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    //self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"]];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setTxtUsername:nil];
    [self setTxtPassword:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}

- (void) alertStatus:(NSString *)msg :(NSString *) title
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:msg delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alertView show];
}

- (IBAction)registerClicked:(id)sender {
    @try {

        if([[txtUsername text] isEqualToString:@""] || [[txtPassword text] isEqualToString:@""] || [[_txtMail text] isEqualToString:@""]) {
            [self alertStatus:@"Porfavor, introduce el usuario y contraseña" :@"Error"];
        } else {
            NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@&mail=%@",[txtUsername text],[txtPassword text],[_txtMail text]];
            NSLog(@"PostData: %@",post);

            NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://autograpp.com/register.php"];

            NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

            NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
            [request setURL:url];
            [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
            [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
            [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
            [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
            [request setHTTPBody:postData];

            [NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[url host]];

            NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
            NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
            NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

            NSLog(@"Response code: %d", [response statusCode]);
            if ([response statusCode] >=200 && [response statusCode] <300)
            {
                NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", responseData);

                SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [SBJsonParser new];
                NSDictionary *jsonData = (NSDictionary *) [jsonParser objectWithString:responseData error:nil];
                NSLog(@"%@",jsonData);
                NSInteger success = [(NSNumber *) [jsonData objectForKey:@"success"] integerValue];
                NSLog(@"%d",success);
                if(success == 1)
                {
                    NSLog(@"Login SUCCESS");
                    [self alertStatus:@"Bienvenido a Autograpp." :@"Datos correctos"];

                } else {

                    NSString *error_msg = (NSString *) [jsonData objectForKey:@"error_message"];
                    [self alertStatus:error_msg :@"Datos incorrectos"];
                }

            } else {
                if (error) NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                [self alertStatus:@"Ha ocurrido un problema inesperado" :@"Error"];
            }
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException * e) {
        NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
        [self alertStatus:@"Error." :@"Error"];
    }
}

- (IBAction)loginClicked:(id)sender {
    @try {

        if([[txtUsername text] isEqualToString:@""] || [[txtPassword text] isEqualToString:@""] ) {
            [self alertStatus:@"Porfavor, introduce el usuario y contraseña" :@"Error"];
        } else {
            NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@",[txtUsername text],[txtPassword text]];
            NSLog(@"PostData: %@",post);

            NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://autograpp.com/login.php"];

            NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

            NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
            [request setURL:url];
            [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
            [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
            [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
            [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
            [request setHTTPBody:postData];

            [NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[url host]];

            NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
            NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
            NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

            NSLog(@"Response code: %d", [response statusCode]);
            if ([response statusCode] >=200 && [response statusCode] <300)
            {
                NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", responseData);

                SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [SBJsonParser new];
                NSDictionary *jsonData = (NSDictionary *) [jsonParser objectWithString:responseData error:nil];
                NSLog(@"%@",jsonData);
                NSInteger success = [(NSNumber *) [jsonData objectForKey:@"success"] integerValue];
                NSLog(@"%d",success);
                if(success == 1)
                {
                    NSLog(@"Login SUCCESS");
                    [self alertStatus:@"Bienvenido a Autograpp." :@"Datos correctos"];

                } else {

                    NSString *error_msg = (NSString *) [jsonData objectForKey:@"error_message"];
                    [self alertStatus:error_msg :@"Datos incorrectos"];
                }

            } else {
                if (error) NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                [self alertStatus:@"Ha ocurrido un problema inesperado" :@"Error"];
            }
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException * e) {
        NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
        [self alertStatus:@"Error." :@"Error"];
    }
}

@end
```

If you see anything wrong, please tell me, because that's my first app and I'm trying to learn.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your coding is fine, u need to implement the navigation controller in front of the root controller

Comment: Thanks Anbu, I really appreciate your help. I have to put a Navigation Controller before the AupViewController? Why? And also I would like to know if you can help me with the redirection process when the user is correctly logged in.

Comment: the reason is u r using storyboard, it is the cernterlized on your app, if u are added the navigation controller in front the root controller,it automatically pass the values or navigate to the child controllers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

your coding is fine, u need to implement the navigation controller in front of the root controller,

and redirect process use `segue` method for the particular view controller, everything is fine use this line

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"identifierName" sender:self];
```

more ref :[more reference here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20715462/receiver-viewcontroller-has-no-segue-with-identifier-addsegue/20715545#20715545)

Comment: any help, i will hope with u

Comment: Much appreciated Anbu, everything perfect and your line code for the redirection is perfect! Thanks again for your help :)