# Segue from code doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, segue

I've created a segue from one VC to another VC (Dragging form the VC to the other VC), and called it RegisterUserSegue , its a Push segue and all my view controllers are embedded in a navigation controller.
I'm calling the segue like this:

`[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"RegisterUserSegue" sender:self];`

and in `performSegueWithIdentifier` I've set an NSLog that is called every time I call the segue, but the viewController doesn't change.

**EDIT:
however if i comment out the  `- (void)performSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender` method, everything works just fine.**

This is the method:

```
- (void)performSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Called");
}
```

help?
thanks!

Comment: More information maybe? Are you using storyboard? Did you define the Segue as `RegisterUserSegue` ??

Comment: @taylorcressy I've wrote that I called the segue `RegisterUserSegue`, and yes I use storyboard.

Comment: have you bind button from where you call segue?

Comment: @Amit its not a button segue, its a custom one.

Comment: So, have you set a breakpoint in `performSegueWithIdentifier` and single stepped through?

Comment: @Paulw11 yes it gets executed.

Comment: Please show that method

Comment: use this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20715462/receiver-viewcontroller-has-no-segue-with-identifier-addsegue/20715545#20715545

Comment: Wait, did you implement `performSegueWithIdentifier` in your view controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By implementing `prepareForSegueWithIdenitifer` you have overridden the default implementation in UIViewController with a method that does nothing (except write to the log).

You could use -

```
- (void)performSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender {
    [super performSegueWithIdentifier:identifier sender:sender];
    NSLog(@"Called");
}
```

But you typically do not override this method. If you want to pass properties through to the destination view controller you would use `prepareForSegue:sender:`