# ObjectiveC > Segue between TableView and ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I'm a beginner in Objective C and I have an issue between my Table View Controller and ViewController. When I click on the cell nothing happens, I don't go in my view controller to have more details about my cell.

I use a push segue and I don't forget to give it an identifier and to do this code part in my TableView:

```
(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDetails"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        ViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.details = data [indexPath.row];
    }
}
```

My link between my two views is between the cell prototype and the ViewController window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetails" sender:self];
    }
```

in prepareForSegue:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDetails"])
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    ViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    destViewController.details = data [indexPath.row];
    }
}
```

Comment: I think now he wants to go in the view however I have this error when I launch the app > 'Receiver (<TableViewController: 0x7f96eae31b70>) has no segue with identifier 'showDetails''

Comment: @Guillaume.M -- what is your segue connection name if it is wrong "showDetails"

Comment: When I click on the segue, I give it the identifier showDetails

Comment: @Guillaume.M -- it is the small mistake , for your error see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20715462/receiver-viewcontroller-has-no-segue-with-identifier-addsegue/20715545#20715545, it helps you