# Can't perform Auto Segue

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, segue

I'm new to iOS dev, I'm trying to switch between storyboards.

I followed the answer provided here ['Receiver (<ViewController>) has no segue with identifier 'addSegue'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20715462/receiver-viewcontroller-has-no-segue-with-identifier-addsegue).

I did every step and put the below code in my viewDidLoad, because I want it to automatically go to a new storyboard, depending no a condition. Am I doing something wrong?

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "identifierName", sender: self)
```

Comment: Have you created segue in storyboard?

Comment: https://youtu.be/cD02mR8UpRk?t=1m38s

Comment: Yes, I did add a segue in my storyboard

Comment: check whether the identifier name is the same as the one given in the storyboard

Comment: I think you're trying to segue too early in the lifecycle of the ViewController.  Try your code in an override of `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: You're correct, I ended up figuring it out, I'm going to post it as answer and accept it, unless you want to do it.

Answer (score 0):

your code is write in prepareForSegue method

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if(segue.identifier == "yourIdentifierInStoryboard")
{
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "identifierName", sender: self)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Vacawama said, it's not possible to do it in the ViewDidLoad, so I've put it in the ViewDidAppear and it works just fine.